# Easy (no code) way to open a form in a lightbox (a plugin?)

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I'd like to open content (text or a simple form) in a lightbox when a user clicks a specific URL. [like this](http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4118/4749456635_5e3f9acae8_o.png)

Every plugin I've found so far opens a lightbox when someone comes to the site or goes to a page -- nothing I've found is setup to open the lightbox when the user clicks on a link.

There are some hacks using Fancybox and jquery -- but if one exists I'd much prefer using a plugin, I'm not to comfortable messing with javascript and the theme files.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a form in a lightbox will take some code.

There is a nice tutorial from Gravity Forms that is pretty basic.  http://www.gravityhelp.com/creating-a-modal-form-with-gravity-forms-and-fancybox/

You basically add the javascript to your theme and create a special blank template to open the form in then add a class to the a tag that links to the form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris. That code doesn't look too bad. I'm a little surprised Gravity or Wufoo or someone else hasn't written a plugin to do the whole thing - but there are probably technical nuances I don't grasp that make that difficult.